# avoid Duplicate entry in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables say, Table1 and Table2.
Table1 contain 20 fileds with primary key ID for Table1 auto increment and Table2 contain same 20 column with primary key  ID1 for TAble2 auto increment.
Table1- ID,Column1,Column2,Column3....,Colunm20.
Table2-ID1,ID,Column1,Column2,.....,Column20
`I insert each record into Table1.` `I want to check duplicate Entry for Table1 if all field are same.` 
Table2 contain the Entry form Table1.`If I modified record First record goes to Table2 as it is then it will update into Table1.(i.e first copy the record into Table2 for backup and then update into Table1)` So, same condition for Duplicate entry check near Table2 also need. Please Help!
I have coded this in php.

Comment: Some code, table DDL, example data and expected result might help.

Comment: Ok I will edit and give table column ok.

Comment: You should accept your previous answers if that has helped you...

Comment: your question is not clear. `If I modified record First record goes to Table2 then ...`

Comment: This much is fine.? I want just logic

Comment: @codehx please check Update line.

Comment: You might want to read about indizes of type `unique` im MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can write trigger for table 1 which is copying data from table2 on every insert event.

And for unique data either you can check it on php side before you insert or you can define column as unique. Your question is bit confusing so Its difficult to give exact answer.

What are the unique columns ??